Cannot change SDDM theme on Kubuntu 24.04
I just installed Kubuntu 24.04 and the default theme is very bright and white, I am trying to select something more dark, but none of the themes (including the breeze) seem to work. I go to system settings, change the theme, hit apply, enter my password, then reboot. Same theme, no change.
Is there something I can do to fix this?
EDIT: If I disable Auto-login, I can adjust the theme. Why would that be?

Turns out I was comparing to lock screen and didn't realize that is a separate preference.
If anyone else has this issue, you gotta look for the lock screen preference pane in settings.
